# Text Carousel Not Working in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Don't Why Its Not Working Please Help! I was also trying it with plain javascript but i want to make it with jquery .

MY HTML

```
  <h1 class="heading">MAKE BIG <span id="flipper">IMPRESSION</span></h1>
```

MY JQUERY

```
  // customized js you can change these setting

(function(){

  // Flipper Slider

  var flipperContent = ['DECISION','MISTAKES','INVENTIONS'];
  var index = 0;

  function flipperSlider(){

    var flipper = $('#flipper');
    var messageLibrary = flipperContent[index];
    flipper.innerHTML = messageLibrary;
    index++;

    if(index >= flipperContent.length){
        index = 0;
    }

   }

   setInterval(flipperSlider,4000);

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flipper` is a jquery object try `flipper[0].innerHTML = messageLibrary` or `flipper.get(0).innerHTML = messageLibrary`

You want something like [this?](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/g95quqma/)

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code a bit.
used `.text` instead of `innerHtml`.
please check the below code snippet or this [Link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJVbae)

```js
(function(){

  // Flipper Slider

  var flipperContent = ['DECISION','MISTAKES','INVENTIONS'];
  var index = 0;

  function flipperSlider(){

    var flipper = $('#flipper');
    var messageLibrary = flipperContent[index];
    flipper.text(messageLibrary) ;
    index++;

    
    if(index >= flipperContent.length){
        index = 0;
    }

   }

   setInterval(function(){flipperSlider()},4000);

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="heading">MAKE BIG <span id="flipper">IMPRESSION</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.html()` as `flipper` is a jQuery object! I've also minimised your code a bit.

```
(function() {

    // Flipper Slider
    var flipperContent = ['DECISION','MISTAKES','INVENTIONS'];
    var index = 0;

    function flipperSlider(){

        $('#flipper').html(flipperContent[index++]);
        index = index === flipperContent.length ? 0 : index;
    }
    setInterval(flipperSlider,1000);
}());
```

Here is [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g95quqma/2/)